# Minecraft Pulser Burns out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

According to [this article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#Clock_generators)

> 1-clocks and 3-clocks are possible to
> make but they will "burn out" because
> of their speed, which makes them
> unstable. Redundancy can be used to
> maintain a 1-clock, even as the
> torches burn out; the result is the
> so-called "Rapid Pulsar"

Whenever I make a 1 clock, it pulses for a bit, then burns out and never comes back on. How do I implement Redundancy which will keep it pulsing?

Comment: I believe what you quoted explains why your problem occurs (instability due to speed) and the solution (redundancy).  Perhaps you should elaborate.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant to ask how to implement Redundancy to keep it pulsing.

Comment: Remember that even if you have a redundant clock, if it's unstable and you try to drive some additional circuitry with it, it will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rapid pulsar works by basically having four 1-clocks, when one burns out another takes over. You can't have a 1-clock by itself without it burning out. The largest stable clock is a 5-clock.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits#Pulse_Generators

Comment: But... how do you wire them all up so that another takes over when one burns out?

Comment: See designs A and F: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_circuits#Clock_generators

Comment: I've built design A, but it always burns out...

Comment: The shadowed block means there should be a block above it. Each of those torches needs a block on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using repeaters, which do not burn out, it is possible to make a one-clock:

[image]

Just inject a one-tick pulse from a [pulse generator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits#Pulse_circuits) to set it going.

Answer (score 0):

Using a solid block(ie dirt), a redstone torch, a redstone repeater and three redstone dust you can make a one clock

r= redstone dust
p= redstone repeater
t= redstone torch
b= solid block

rpb
rrt
By setting the repeater to three ticks, you get an effective pulser